# Расположение команд в группе

Tags: javascript

```js
var teamsFirst = [
    { name: "Barcelona", country: "Spain" },
    { name: "Real Madrid", country: "Spain" },
    { name: "MU", country: "England" },
    { name: "Totenham", country: "England" }
];

var teamsSecond = [
    { name: "Atletico Madrid", country: "Spain" },
    { name: "Valencia", country: "Spain" },
    { name: "Chelsea", country: "England" },
    { name: "Arsenal", country: "England" }
];

var groupA = [];
var groupB = [];
var groupC = [];
var groupD = [];

var groups = [
    groupA, groupB, groupC, groupD
];

function compareRandom() {
    return Math.random() - 0.5;
}

function printTeams() {
    for ( let i = 0; i < groups.length; i += 1 ) {
        console.log('Group ' + i + ": " + groups[i][0].name + " and " + groups[i][1].name);
    }
}

function checkTeams() {
    var response = false;

    for ( var i = 0; i < groups.length; i += 1 ) {
        if ( groups[i][0].country === groups[i][1].country ) {
            response = true;
        }
    }

    return response;
}

function cleanGroups() {
    groupA = [];
    groupB = [];
    groupC = [];
    groupD = [];
}

    for ( var j = 0; j < 100; j++ ) {
        teamsFirst.sort(compareRandom);
        teamsSecond.sort(compareRandom);

        for ( let i = 0; i < groups.length; i += 1 ) {
            groups[i].push(teamsFirst[i]);
            groups[i].push(teamsSecond[i]);
        }

        var answer = checkTeams();

        if (!answer) {
            printTeams();
            break;
        } else {
            cleanGroups();
        }
    }
```

Задача программы - сортировать команды в группы так, чтобы в одной группе не было команд с одной и той же страны. Проблема заключается в следующем: если последний `for` заменить на `while`, то программа будет выполняться бесконечно, и команды никогда не выведутся в консоль. Но, если `for` оставить, то они иногда появляются. Как исправить программу так, чтобы происходила сортировка команд, потом проверка ( есть ли команды в одной группе одинаковыми странами ), и в конце - вывод?

Comment: Нужно распределить команды по группам, без совпадений с одной и той же страны?

Comment: Да, всё верно. В одной группе не может быть две команды из одной и той же страны ( прим: в одной группе не могут быть Челси и МЮ )

Comment: Сам код работает, если использую for ( проходит 1000 раз ) и когда в одной группе нет команд из одной страны - они выводятся, но не всегда, так как за 1000 раз команды могут не быть правильно рассеяны. Но если поставить while, то код выполняется бесконечно

Answer (score 1):

Перебираем команды первой группы и для каждой ищем первую подходящую из второй. Подходящие из второй убираем совсем чтоб они не продублировались в другой паре.

```js
let teamsFirst = [
    { name: "Barcelona", country: "Spain" },
    { name: "Real Madrid", country: "Spain" },
    { name: "MU", country: "England" },
    { name: "Totenham", country: "England" }
];

let teamsSecond = [
    { name: "Atletico Madrid", country: "Spain" },
    { name: "Valencia", country: "Spain" },
    { name: "Chelsea", country: "England" },
    { name: "Arsenal", country: "England" }
];

let groupA = [],
    groupB = [],
    groupC = [],
    groupD = [];

let groups = [
    groupA, groupB, groupC, groupD
];

function compareRandom(a, b)
{
    return Math.random() - 0.5;
}

function printTeams()
{
    for (let i = 0; i < groups.length; i++) {
        console.log(`Group #${i}: ${groups[i][0].name} (${groups[i][0].country}) VS ${groups[i][1].name} (${groups[i][1].country})`);
    }
}

teamsFirst.sort(compareRandom);
teamsSecond.sort(compareRandom);

for (let f = 0, first; f < teamsFirst.length; f++) {
    first = teamsFirst[f];
    groups[f].push(first);

    for (let s = 0, second; s < teamsSecond.length; s++) {
        second = teamsSecond.shift();
        if (second.country !== first.country) {
            groups[f].push(second);
            break;
        }
        teamsSecond.push(second);
  }
}

printTeams();
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var teamsFirst = [
    { name: "Barcelona", country: "Spain" },
    { name: "Real Madrid", country: "Spain" },
    { name: "MU", country: "England" },
    { name: "Totenham", country: "England" }
];

var teamsSecond = [
    { name: "Atletico Madrid", country: "Spain" },
    { name: "Valencia", country: "Spain" },
    { name: "Chelsea", country: "England" },
    { name: "Arsenal", country: "England" }
];

var groupA = [];
var groupB = [];
var groupC = [];
var groupD = [];

var groups = [
    groupA, groupB, groupC, groupD
];

function randomIntegr() {
  var random = Math.random() * 4;
  return Math.floor(random);
}


function randomGroups(teams) {
teams.forEach(team =>{
var random = randomIntegr();
if (!groups[random].length){
  groups[random].push(team);
} else if (groups[random].some(item => {return item.country !== team.country}) && groups[random].length < 2){        
  groups[random].push(team);
} else {
  for (group of groups){
    if (!group.length){
      group.push(team);
      break;
    } else if (group.some(item => {return item.country  !== team.country}) && group.length < 2){
      group.push(team);
      break;
    }
  }
}
})
}

randomGroups(teamsFirst);
randomGroups(teamsSecond);
for (val of groups){
  console.log(`${val[0].name} vs ${val[1].name}`);
}
```

Comment: Одна и та же команда попадает в более чем одну группу.

Comment: Спасибо, не заметил изначально.